# Pulling off into or over next string

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, technique

When performing a pull off on guitar, is there a consensus on whether you should pull off into the next higher string or "across" it? The former does not require muting that string with the right hand but may produce a slightly different tone and/or hinder fast playing. But I am not sure if that is just because of my lack of technique.

EDIT: clarifying what I mean by "into" and "across":

With the left hand finger performing the pull off, do I either:

a) Pull of so that at the end of the motion the finger rests against the next higher string (e.g. the g string if pulling off from the d string), muting it.

Or:

b) Pull of so that the finger plucks the next higher string (because completely avoiding that is impossible, right?) but ends up in the air at the end of the motion.

Comment: What do you mean by across? Do you mean along the same string?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Admittedly my description is a bit confusing, I mean with the left hand finger performing the pull off, either:

a) pull of so that at the end of the motion the finger rests against the next higher string (e.g. the g string if pulling off from the d string), muting it.
b) pull of so that the finger plucks the next higher string (because completely avoiding that is impossible, right?) but ends up in the air at the end of the motion

Comment: Thanks, why not edit your question and add your description?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I have edited the question and accepted your answer, it sounds logical and I will try practicing it this way from now on.

Comment: c) avoid hitting the other string. it is possible to pull off without touching other strings. it's just something that takes practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull off and rest on the next higher string but this is a bit counterintuitive because it leaves your pull off finger in a position where it might be out of position to do whatever you want to do next. If you pull off towards the higher string and even touch it but immediately lift it, the finger is in a better position to continue whatever may come next. As far as not touching the higher string, it is not easy but it is possible to pull off without touching the higher string, especially higher up the neck where the strings are spaced further apart. In general it is not really necessary to avoid the higher string with some simple muting.

As far as muting, using the plucking hand isn’t necessary. Let’s  say you are doing a 3-1 pull off. You can mute the higher string with the first finger of the fingering hand easily by flattening it out a bit and lightly touching the higher string with it.

Sometimes pull offs are done in rapid succession or combined repeatedly with hammer-ons. In this case the lifting is even more important because you have to rhythmically pull off or alternate the pull/hammer. What you end up with is a continuous elliptical or circular motion of the pull off/hammer finger in order to get speed and consistency. This would be very hard to do if you rested your finger on the lower string when pulling off.

Comment: When you say "especially higher up the neck where the strings are spaced further apart" are you referring to the upright bass? Because on guitar the strings are the same distance apart (and also very tightly spaced on non-classical instruments) everywhere, making this pretty tricky.

Comment: @Peter - I don't think I've ever seen a guitar with a parallel neck. They all get wider towards the top. Probably the least variation would be a Rickenbacker [4001 etc], but even that is *slightly* wider at the top.

Comment: @Peter You tagged guitar so I am only referring to guitar. Measure the width from E to E at the bridge and at the nut and compare. On nylon string guitars the difference is less but with the exception of perhaps a few unusual custom instruments they all fan out as they get higher.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy You are right, I honestly never noticed. Simultaneously it feels like the increased action for higher frets makes it somewhat more difficult.

Comment: @Peter You may want to check your setup, especially your neck relief. You might need a truss rod and action adjustment. The strings shouldn’t get a lot higher in the upper register, just slightly. If you’re a DIY type there are plenty of good instructional videos about setup available.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend a lot on what comes next. Most frequently, the next note will be on a lower string - the adjacent one, on whatever fret. When that's the case, chances are the finger used to pull off will be needed for that next note, so keeping the pull as short as possible (not even getting to the next higher pitched string) is advantageous.

If, on the rarer occasion, the next note is on that higher pitched string, then depending what fret it's on will be the decider as to whether you get straight onto the string or stop when touching it.

Another scenario is when trilling. Here, the pull-off finger needs to be back on the upper fret a.s.a.p., probably hammered-on. So a slightly different motion comes into play. more of a circular one, where the finger plucks the string and doesn't get near the next one to it.

Answer (score -1):

when i pull off it's either from a tap (which is easier to attack vertically without hitting any other strings) or I lift the string a little before flicking to keep clear of any other strings.

unless you intended on using the other strings for effect, work on avoiding them all together

i forgot that where heavy bending is involved, the fretting finger can catch any strings in the way and pull them silently with the bend.

play really loud through your amp, this makes it really hard to perform but easier to get the technique down

Comment: what's wih the negativity... check out this for non believers https://youtu.be/s345iYR2tpU?si=JOY2xPrZr9Wma7Q7